# Code execution flow using Enterprise Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, enterprise-architect

We have large C# ASP.NET application, the code base is so huge that I need some tool to visualize how the execution flow through the code. I am only having VS 2013 Professional Edition and there is not a chance of getting Ultimate edition.

Is there any way to get Code execution flow diagram using VS 2013 Professional?

Also I am trying Enterprise Architect to view the execution flow, But I don't know how to use EA.

Anyone can give me walk through about how I use EA to view execution flow of ASP.NET application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enterprise Architect can not (as far as I know) reverse engineer behavioral aspects using static code analysis.

But there is an "**Execution Analyzer**" available, which can create UML sequence diagram from running code.

See

- appropriate chapters in the help file
- and article http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2012/03/13/tutorial-nunit-and-sequence-diagram-recording-in-enterprise-architect-9-3/ for a short tutorial
- and webinar recording http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/vea/webinar-visual-execution-analyzer.html for discussion of some wider context.

However, as far as I know **there are no auto-magic-bullet tools** that would replace missing documentation by reverse engineering and visualizing legacy code bases.

Article [Agile Modeling: Single Source Information: An Agile Best Practice for Effective Documentation](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/singleSourceInformation.htm) can give you some insights and decision points which parts you should document. But the simplest hint probably is: **create documentation explaining things you don't understand, using whatever set of simple and semi-automatic and efficient tools that you have available**. e.g. [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/features/dependency-graph-matrix-architecture#DependenciesView) is one falling into this category.

This broad subject is off-topic on Stack Overflow and you can find better help on the Programmers StackExchange site, you can start with question [Programmers: How do you dive into large code bases?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/how-do-you-dive-into-large-code-bases)