# Generate EA Sequence Diagrams from Application

Tags: enterprise-architect, auto-generate, sequence-diagram

Is there an option to integrate an application to Enterprise Architect to then generate sequence diagrams automatically?

I so not mean to record a sequence diagram from debugger.  I mean integrating EA to an EXE application.

Any material on this topic would be appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "Integrating EA to an EXE application"

Comment: If you mean, to reverse engineer data from a commercially available compiled program, you'll probably find that is against the EULA of the program anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code execution flow using Enterprise Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460519/code-execution-flow-using-enterprise-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are asking for would require the code to be de-compiled to the appropriate language and then have EA reverse engineer.