# How to generate sequence diagrams for C# from Enterprise Architect[Reverse Engineering]

Tags: c#, uml, enterprise-architect

I already have the C# code how can I generate sequence diagrams in Enterprise Architect? I have been trying a lot.I am able to generate only class diagrams.

Comment: There is some tutorial on Sparx' site. Basically you need to attach to a debugger so EA can log the calls. I haven't done that for myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code execution flow using Enterprise Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460519/code-execution-flow-using-enterprise-architecture)