# How to generate Sequence Diagram of Java Eclipse Project from Enterprise Architect

Tags: java, eclipse, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

How can we generate Sequence Diagram from Enterprise Architect by reverse engineering of JAVA Eclipse Ant project. The eclipse project is a web application deployed on tomcat

Comment: You need to run the code like described on Sparx' website. You can not create SDs from pure code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code execution flow using Enterprise Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460519/code-execution-flow-using-enterprise-architecture)

Comment: I am using language Java and followed the below tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipdF0bcOqfo  . But when click for recording . i.e.> Execute > Recorder> Attach  to a process  i get th following error : There was an error parsing E:\Giggal\workspace\MS\.project  on line 1.  Unexpected symbol: < 
You may need to define a language macro.  Please suggest

Comment: That's a different question which DOES have an answer.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian Its the same question with further update  Please provide some solution